# How to obtain reference to all html elements inside a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to obtain an array of all li tags within an element that have a specific class. The problem I seem to get when I run this on my project is it won't give me a reference to all the elements and instead seems to return `[prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]`. Thanks

```js
const allElements = $('.some-elements li');
console.log(allElements);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="some-elements">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: This yields `Object { 0: <li>, 1: <li>, 2: <li>, length: 3, prevObject: Object[1] }` for me.

Comment: Look at .get();

Comment: Interesting... The ideal situation would be an array of all the li elements so I can loop through them. I'm wondering if descendant class selectors in jquery simply work differently then I was told to believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `jQuery` instead of `$` as some other library may be using `$`

```js
const allElements = jQuery('.some-elements li');

console.log(allElements);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="some-elements">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.some-elements li');
```

It will return an array of elements.

Comment: It will return a `NodeList`, not an `Array`. For an Array, use `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.some-elements li'));`.